# Concurrently Uploading Multiple Image Gets Corrupted

Tags: node.js, express

Trying to upload multiple file using [busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy), The file may be large size So, I'm uploading asynchronous, I'm using `file.on('data')`

When I request a API continuously with some delay(>3s) the function is working fine, If I request a API continuously(without delay)/parallelly/concurrently some image got missing or corrupted.

```
app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
    var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        var writeStream = [];
        writeStream[fieldname] = fs.createWriteStream('./tmp/tmp' + Date.now());
        console.log('File [' + fieldname + ']: filename: ' + filename + ', encoding: ' + encoding + ', mimetype: ' + mimetype);
        file.on('data', function (data) {
            console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] got ' + data.length + ' bytes');
            writeStream[fieldname].write(data);
        });
        file.on('end', function () {
            console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] Finished');
            writeStream[fieldname].end();
        });
    });
    busboy.on('finish', function () {
        console.log('Upload complete');
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Connection': 'close' });
        res.end("That's all folks!");
    });
    return req.pipe(busboy);
});
```